# Url matching in java web application

Tags: java, url, servlets

In the context of url matching in java web applications, what is the difference between `*`  `/` and `*.*`

Which of these patterns includes the others?
Shouldn't `*` pattern accept `/` and `*.*` as well, Since a `*` wildcard should include everything else.

Please feel free to point to resources that explain this further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An URL pattern of `*` or, more correct, `/*`  (the leading forward slash is namely implicit on path-mapped URL patterns) matches *everything*. This thus also matches requests which would end up in `/`. This URL pattern is more common for a [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) than for a [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).

An URL pattern of `/` matches only requests which didn't match any of the other definied URL patterns. It becomes then the "default" servlet (and it will override the servletcontainer's builtin default servlet!).

The `*.*` is not a valid URL pattern.

This is all definied in chapter 12 of the [Servlet API specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/index.html) (on the linked site, click the download button of the one *for evaluation*).